# Randomly Generate Planets

Tags: java, game, android

This is code I'm writing for an android game where I want to be able to randomly generate small planet sprites. It seems like the best way to do this is to have a set of small PNG textures that can be layered onto each other. I found code for recolouring a drawable programmatically [here](http://takeoffandroid.com/android/changing-color-of-drawable-icon-programmatically/) that was very helpful.

The idea is that the `Planet` object will randomly choose attributes on creation. This makes it easier to save the data rather than having the `Drawables` themselves stored as part of the object. My intent is to have a backlog of these saved so that by the end of the game I can redraw all the ones you've seen. So data storage and later retrieval is important.

Once the `Planet` has been created then there's the `getDrawable` method that can be called to actually return a `LayerDrawable` object, which layers the textures onto each other as you'd expect.

I'd like to know particularly if I'm performing right and matching Android coding style. I don't Java or Android terribly well so quite possibly I have some bad code smell plopped in here. In particular, how should I be commenting? Python has docstrings (programmatically accessible comments with a clear format guideline) but is there any similar guideline for how to detail the functions in Java?

```
package com.chadwick.laika;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.Random;

public class Planet {

    private Context context;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int[] palette;
    private String[] layers;

    public Planet(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        palette = randomPalette();
        layers = getLayers();
    }

    public int[] randomPalette() {
        String id = "palette" + random.nextInt(2);
        int palette = context.getResources().getIdentifier(id, "array", context.getPackageName());
        return context.getResources().getIntArray(palette);
    }

    // Randomly pick a base and textures to layer onto the base, then store their codes
    private String[] getLayers(){
        String[] layers = new String[random.nextInt(3) + 2];

        int base_id = random.nextInt(3);
        layers[0] = "base" + base_id;

        for (int i = 1; i < layers.length; i++){
            String code = "texture" + base_id + "_" + random.nextInt(6);
            layers[i] = code;
        }

        return layers;
    }

    // Apply color to source. source must be a purely white drawable (can have transparency)
    public Drawable colourDrawable(Drawable source, int color) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                source.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        source.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        source.draw(canvas);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color, 1);
        p.setColorFilter(filter);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, p);
        return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
    }

    // Takes stored image codes and palette to generate the LayerDrawable
    public LayerDrawable getDrawable(){
        Drawable[] pictures = new Drawable[layers.length];
        int base = context.getResources().getIdentifier(layers[0], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        pictures[0] = colourDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, base), palette[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < layers.length; i++) {
            int texture = context.getResources().getIdentifier(layers[1], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            pictures[1] = colourDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, texture), palette[i]);
        }
        return new LayerDrawable(pictures);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to know more about using [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) for documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bug?

```
public LayerDrawable getDrawable(){
    Drawable[] pictures = new Drawable[layers.length];
    int base = context.getResources().getIdentifier(layers[0], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    pictures[0] = colourDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, base), palette[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < layers.length; i++) {
        int texture = context.getResources().getIdentifier(layers[1], "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        pictures[1] = colourDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, texture), palette[i]);
    }
    return new LayerDrawable(pictures);
}
```

What I see here is that you go through the layers, and turn it into a set of pictures. That's your intention, at least. That's why you do `new Drawable[layers.length]`. But then you loop through the layers and just read `layers[1]` and write `pictures[1]` and the only thing `i` is ever used for is `palette`...

If it's because of the similarity between `i` and `1`, configure your editor to use different colors for (local) variables and numbers.

Also, that function looks like it does a lot of work. I don't know a lot about android, so maybe this is a bad thing to do, but could the drawables be cached?

### Magic Numbers & Unnecessary local store

```
private String[] getLayers(){
    String[] layers = new String[random.nextInt(3) + 2];

    int base_id = random.nextInt(3);
    layers[0] = "base" + base_id;

    for (int i = 1; i < layers.length; i++){
        String code = "texture" + base_id + "_" + random.nextInt(6);
        layers[i] = code;
    }

    return layers;
}
```

You have `random.nextInt` with 3, then +2, and 3 somewhere else, and 6 somewhere else again...

I don't know what they mean. You have apparently 2-4 layers each but the top(?) textured with a random 0-5 subtextures... which seems oddly rigid to me, why 6 different subtextures, why not 5, why not 7...

```
        String code = "texture" + base_id + "_" + random.nextInt(6);
        layers[i] = code;
```

That's an unnecessary local store. You don't do anything with the variable, and it doesn't have a name that clarifies anything. I'd remove it, just put the following in your for loop:

```
layers[i] = "texture" + base_id + "_" + random.nextInt(6);
```